# How to parse related data and store the values to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse through a web page, collect values and store them to a database.

Here is my code with commented-out database code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://example.com/colors"))
colors = doc.css(".colorCircle")
colors_name = doc.css(".zw-m-c-txt")    

 colors.each do |ele|   
    hex_code = ele.attr('style').split(";").first.split(":").last       

    colors_name.each do |name|
        color_name = name.text
        puts " ++++++ hex_code #{hex_code}" 
        puts " ++++++ color_name  #{color_name}"
        # color = colors.find_by(:hex_code => hex_code)
        # if color.present?
        #               color.update_attributes(:name => color_name)
        #           else
        #               model.colors.create(:name => color_name, :hex_code => hex_code)
        #           end
    end
end
```

Here is the HTML source page detail:

```
 <span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#EEEFF4;"></span>
 <p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> White Orchid Pearl </span></p>
 <span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#ACABB0;"></span>
 <p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> Modern Steel Metallic </span></p>
 <span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#220909;"></span>
 <p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> Golden Brown Metallic </span></p>
 <span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#43161b;"></span>
 <p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> Carnelian Red Pearl </span></p>
 <span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#E8F1FA;"></span>
 <p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> Alabaster Silver </span></p>
```

I am not able to loop through it sequentially and store to the database.  Here is the current output:

```
++++++ color_name    White Orchid Pearl 
++++++ hex_code #EEEFF4
++++++ color_name    White Orchid Pearl 
++++++ hex_code #ACABB0
++++++ color_name    White Orchid Pearl 
++++++ hex_code #220909
++++++ color_name    White Orchid Pearl 
++++++ hex_code #43161b
++++++ color_name    White Orchid Pearl 
++++++ hex_code #E8F1FA
++++++ color_name    Modern Steel Metallic 
++++++ hex_code #EEEFF4
++++++ color_name    Modern Steel Metallic 
++++++ hex_code #ACABB0
++++++ color_name    Modern Steel Metallic 
++++++ hex_code #220909
++++++ color_name    Modern Steel Metallic 
++++++ hex_code #43161b
++++++ color_name    Modern Steel Metallic
```

This is the expected output:

```
hex_code      #EEEFF4
color_name    White Orchid Pearl 
hex_code      #ACABB0
color_name    Modern Steel Metallic
hex_code      #220909
color_name    Golden Brown Metallic
```

How do I get the expected output and save it to a database corresponding `hex_code` with the color name?

Comment: So you want to associate each color name with the background-color from the span? E.g. White Orchid Pearl with #EEEFF4 ?

Comment: You realize you have a two nested for loops and you basically run through each color_name for each color.

Comment: @radubogdan Yes your are correct, I want to associate each color name with bkg-color from span.

Comment: Parsing the information from HTML is one question not related to writing that data to a database. I'd recommend removing the code and any mention that it save to the database to clarify the question. SO is about clear and concise questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do if I wanted that data:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA.read)

data = doc.search('.colorCircle').map { |span|
  hex = span['style'][/#([^;]+);$/, 1]
  color = span.next_element.at('span').text.strip
  [ hex, color ]
}.to_h
# => {"EEEFF4"=>"White Orchid Pearl",
#     "ACABB0"=>"Modern Steel Metallic",
#     "220909"=>"Golden Brown Metallic",
#     "43161b"=>"Carnelian Red Pearl",
#     "E8F1FA"=>"Alabaster Silver"}

__END__
<span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#EEEFF4;"></span>
<p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> White Orchid Pearl </span></p>
<span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#ACABB0;"></span>
<p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> Modern Steel Metallic </span></p>
<span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#220909;"></span>
<p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> Golden Brown Metallic </span></p>
<span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#43161b;"></span>
<p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> Carnelian Red Pearl </span></p>
<span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#E8F1FA;"></span>
<p class="zw-m-c-txt"> <span class="fnt-14"> Alabaster Silver </span></p>
```

Which, when used with:

```
data.each do |k, v|
  puts "hex_code: %s\ncolor_name: %s" % [k, v]
end
```

would output:

```
hex_code: EEEFF4
color_name: White Orchid Pearl
hex_code: ACABB0
color_name: Modern Steel Metallic
hex_code: 220909
color_name: Golden Brown Metallic
hex_code: 43161b
color_name: Carnelian Red Pearl
hex_code: E8F1FA
color_name: Alabaster Silver
```

But, there are tables all over the internet with these associations. Rather than parse one and try to inject it into a database table, I'd recommend finding one and create a module or class that stores the data as constants or hashes so you don't have to hit the database to extract the values. You want the absolutely fastest access possible if you're using those values to set colors in pages, or even if you're presenting the correlations of the values to the color names. Or create a static page that is already rendered, as these associations and definitions are not going to change.

Databases are great for some things, but this doesn't seem like a good time for it.

---

This

```
ele.attr('style').split(";").first.split(":").last
```

is brutal.

Extracting the hex-code from the string is a great application for string slicing or a regular expression. You could do it multiple ways:

```
style = "background-color:#EEEFF4;"

style.split(':').last.chop # => "#EEEFF4"
style[-8..-2] # => "#EEEFF4"
style[/(#\h{3,6});$/, 1] # => "#EEEFF4"
```

Using a slice `[-8..-2]` is probably the most error-prone because it assumes the value is always six characters long, which hex values for colors don't have to be. `#FFF` is equivalent to `#FFFFFF` for instance, so handling three or six character variants is important.

In my example above I used `/#([^;]+);$/` which isn't quite as concise as `/(#\h{3,6});$/`, but they've both got tradeoffs so take your pick if you want to use a regex. And how they work is for you to figure out, just remember that not everything is an opportunity to hit the data with the golden regular expression hammer; Use them when they're the best tool because they can open the door to darkness and usher in the lord of the bugs.

And, I deliberately excluded the `#` in the hex values. Adding it wastes space on a redundant character for lookups and in tables but your mileage might vary.

Comment: Thank you @theTinMan, very nice explanation.

Comment: your code works if i read the data from DATA.read however if i try to read data directly from web i get following error.`in block in <main>: undefined method 'at' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` noticed that `span` contains only one line `<span class="colorCircle" style="background-color:#EEEFF4;"></span>` it does not contain next tags. So i tried specifying two classes in search `data = doc.search('.colorCircle, .zw-m-c-txt').map `  still get above mentioned error. could you please guide me where its going wrong.

Comment: I can't help you since I have no idea where you're reading the data from. "[mcve]" says you need a minimal input example in the question that demonstrates the problem, which I used, so possibly the HTML you gave wasn't accurate.  I'd recommend using `nokogiri` at the command-line and pass it the URL you're using, then see if you can find the node you're looking for. It might be the page uses DHTML and only browsers can find it.

Comment: thanks for the response. I did try using `nokogiri` at the command-line however could not solve the issue. here is the exact example link which i'm trying [link](https://www.zigwheels.com/newcars/Honda/City)

Comment: I'd suggest learning about how DHTML works, and how to identify when a page is using it. The `span` tag hasn't been populated because the JavaScript hasn't been run. Nokogiri can't run JavaScript, it's only a HTML/XML parser. SO and many other sites talk about this. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nokogiri+parse+javascript